# Rapid scheduling and cancellation of timed tasks in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm doing some IO with a remote device that sends me updates pretty quickly (say 60 times a second). I get the data through an InputStream object. In the unlikely event that InputStream.read() blocks, I need to detect this to fix the block (try resetting the connection, etc). Every time I issue a read() call I want a parallel timeout that will wait a certain amount of time before calling a method.

There seem to be many ways to do timed task execution in Android/Java. Timers, Threads, Executors, etc. What's the most efficient way to do this specifically taking into account how quickly the scheduled tasks are assigned and canceled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlers are also specialized for scheduling delayed tasks. You can easily schedule task using:

```
 private void scheduleButAlsoReschedule(final View v){
            v.getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            v.getHandler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                // do something here, Note: this is UI-thread
                }}, DISMISS_DELAY);
        }
```

`v.getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`

Removes any callbacks or messages that are currently in the queue. You can also specify which Runnable to be removed from the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any comments on how this compares to some of the other methods I've listed? It seems like a Handler with a Thread running a Looper is somewhat 'bare-bones' (which is good because hopefully this translates into better performance compared to using the more abstract Executor stuff which might create/destroy threads on demand, etc)